# Change colour of table cells depending on value

Tags: jquery, html-table, each

I'm using jQuery to edit the `background-color` of table cells. My code is as follows (the each cell has numbers in the format "x/y" so I mine them out at the start):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#overview td").click(function(event){

                var content = $(this).html();
                var vals = content.split("/");
                var ratio = vals[0]/vals[1];
                alert(ratio);


                var red;
                var green;

                if(vals[1] == 0){
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                } else{
                    if(ratio > 0.5){
                        red = 255;
                        green = parseInt(-2*255*ratio+(2*255));
                    } else{
                        green = 255;
                        red = parseInt(2*255*ratio);
                    }   
                    var rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green+ ', 0)';
                    var hexColor = rgb2hex(rgbColor);
                    $(this).css('background-color', hexColor);
                }
            });
        });
```

Now this works when I click on each individual cell, but I would like to colour all of the cells on `$(document).ready()`. I think the `.each()` method may be what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to make it work properly...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to simply replace the word `click` with the word `each`, and probably want to remove the `event` parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work, I think `this` is required to get the values out and tell it which cell to change?
Also, thanks for noticing `event`, it was a leftover from a previous attempt :)

Comment: I think you may be getting slightly confused with the `event` object and the `this` object, the `event` object is passed by the mouse being clicked, the this object is the current target object, in this case the `this` is the cell you are currently iterating over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nunners, there were header values that broke the code. I've fixed it using the following if block:

```
if(vals[1] == undefined){
    return true;
} else{
    //change colour
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as Jason P mentioned the following code should work fine :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#overview td").each(function () {

                var content = $(this).html();
                var vals = content.split("/");
                var ratio = vals[0] / vals[1];
                alert(ratio);


                var red;
                var green;

                if (vals[1] == 0) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                } else {
                    if (ratio > 0.5) {
                        red = 255;
                        green = parseInt(-2 * 255 * ratio + (2 * 255));
                    } else {
                        green = 255;
                        red = parseInt(2 * 255 * ratio);
                    }
                    var rgbColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ', 0)';
                    var hexColor = rgb2hex(rgbColor);
                    $(this).css('background-color', hexColor);
                }
            });
        });
```

The .each method is just simply an iteration over the retrieved objects.

Comment: Unfortunately if I try this, the `alert(ratio);` line returns NaN and no colours are changed!

Comment: Could you supply your HTML for the table you are attempting this on? If the value is returned as NaN then one of your values (vals[0] or vals[1]) is not a numeric number. You could try checking for this and handling the error using if statements or a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#overview td").click(function (event) {
        // ...
    })
    .trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: this also returns `ratio == NaN`, as `this` is required to get the values out I think?

Comment: It means that some of your cells does not have appropriate data ( `content = $(this).html()`).