# Colouring cells depending on what value is in the cell

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the polarity variable, and change the color of that row depending on the value, for example, 1,2 and 3. Any ideas of how i could do this. 
I tried this, but it is not working. Thankyou.

```
$("#tableView").click(function(event){
    $('#empty').html('');
    $('#empty').show();
    $('.content').addClass('hide');
    var tweet;
    var i;
    $('#empty').append('<div><table><tr><th>Tweet</th><th>Polarity</th></tr></table></div>');

    $('.tab-content > .active span').each(function() {
        tweet = $(this).text().slice(0,-2);
        var polarity = $(this).find('.change').text();

           $('table').append('<tr><td>'+ tweet + '</td><td>'+ polarity + '</td></tr>');     
           if($('polarity:contains("1")').css('background-color', 'red'));   
    });
});
```

This is html where i am getting the data from database using PHP, and setting a button to show the data.

```
<div class="parliamentContainer">
 <h1>Parliament</h1>

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

 <li class="active"></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bbc">BBC Parliament</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#minister">Ministers</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#law">Law</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#crime">Crime</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#seeAllPar">See All</a></li>

 </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<button type="button" id="tableView"> Show in table form</button>

<div id= "empty"></div>

<div class="content tab-pane fade" id = "bbc"> 
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parliament WHERE tweet LIKE '%bbc%';",$db);
if (!$result) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<span>".$row[0]. "<p class='change'>".$row[1]."</p> </span>";
}
?>
</div>
```

This is the table element, within my html.

```
<style>
 table, td, th {    
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 text-align: left;
}

 table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 40%;
}

 th, td {
 padding: 10px;
}


  </style>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html you use ? or adding on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: maybe the d3.js library would be interesting for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change colour of table cells depending on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992382/change-colour-of-table-cells-depending-on-value)

Comment: I have added a section of the html where I am getting the data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the below could work (based on my understanding of your question)

**Edit**
Here is a working example. I removed the `> .active`  part of the selector since the element that will have the "active" class is also not specified in the HTML provided.

```js
$("#tableView").click(function(event) {
  $('#empty').html('');
  $('#empty').show();
  $('.content').addClass('hide');
  var tweet;
  var i;
  $('#empty').append('<div><table><tr><th>Tweet</th><th>Polarity</th></tr></table></div>');
  $('.tab-content span').each(function() {
    tweet = $(this).text().slice(0, -2);
    var polarity = $(this).find('.change').text();

    // Save jQuery object in a variable
    var $row = $('<tr><td>' + tweet + '</td><td>' + polarity + '</td></tr>');

    // Update the jQuery object's color based on the 'polarity' variable
    if (polarity == '1') {
      $row.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    // Other sample colors
    if (polarity == '2') {
      $row.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
    if (polarity == '3') {
      $row.css('background-color', 'green');
    }

    // Append the jQuery object
    $('table').append($row);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parliamentContainer">
  <h1>Parliament</h1>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li class="active"></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bbc">BBC Parliament</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#minister">Ministers</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#law">Law</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#crime">Crime</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#seeAllPar">See All</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <button type="button" id="tableView"> Show in table form</button>

    <div id="empty"></div>

    <div class="content tab-pane fade" id="bbc">
      <span>test<p class='change'>1</p> </span>
      <span>test<p class='change'>2</p> </span>
      <span>test<p class='change'>1</p> </span>
      <span>test<p class='change'>3</p> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is colouring the full table red, instead on the particular variables which has 1,2 or 3? any idea in why this would be?

Comment: Which element would have the ".active" class? I cannot find it on the html you provided, also can you include the table element in the html.

Comment: ".active", is the class which depends on which ahref is clicked on, then that tab becomes active to then get the id and content within that active div tag. It is set in my list at the beginning of the html section. Yes i will include the table element now. Thank you for your help

Comment: It is now working and changing the color of the row according to the value, however it is only displaying the first row, where i need to display them all? any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, since it's already working fine on my example. Have you checked if the output spans is similar to the format in my demo?

Comment: It was a simple mistake with my tags, Thank you so much for your help. I have got it working.